# Why is fread_s not working in this C code?

Tags: c, file, pointers, fread

Though all arguments are correct, it returns the right value of items read, the function fread_s doesn't story anything in "bytes" it's empty. It's also empty when I swap 10485760 & 1. Does anyone know what causes this problem? There are no problems with the file at all.

```
float EncryptBig(CRYPTIN* handle)
{
    int i, index = 0;
    float calc;
    char* bytes;

    i = (handle->size - handle->huidig);
    if ((i-10485760) < 0)
    {
        bytes = (char*)malloc(i);
        if (bytes == NULL)
        {
            fcloseall();
            free(handle);
            return 100.0f;
        }

        fread_s(&bytes, i, 1, i, handle->bestand); // Here and down below
        fclose(handle->bestand);

        for (index = 0; index < i; index++)
        {
            __asm
            {
                mov         eax, dword ptr [bytes]  
                add         eax, dword ptr [index]  
                mov         cl, byte ptr [eax]
                xor         cl, 101
                xor         cl, 53
                not         cl
                mov         byte ptr [eax], cl 
                mov         eax, dword ptr [index]  
                add         eax, 1  
                mov         dword ptr [index], eax
            }
        }

        fwrite(bytes, 1, i, handle->nieuwbstnd);
        fclose(handle->nieuwbstnd);
        free(handle);
        free(bytes);

        return 100.0f;
    }

    if (handle->huidig == 0)
    {
        fseek(handle->bestand, 0, SEEK_SET);
        fseek(handle->nieuwbstnd, 0, SEEK_SET);
    }

    bytes = (char*)malloc(10485760);
    if (bytes == NULL)
    {
        fcloseall();
        free(handle);
        return 100.0f;
    }
    fread_s(bytes, 10485760, 10485760, 1, handle->bestand); // Here

    for (index = 0; index < 10485760; index++)
    {
        __asm
        {
            mov         eax, dword ptr [bytes]  
            add         eax, dword ptr [index]  
            mov         cl, byte ptr [eax]
            xor         cl, 101
            xor         cl, 53
            not         cl
            mov         byte ptr [eax], cl 
            mov         eax, dword ptr [index]  
            add         eax, 1  
            mov         dword ptr [index], eax
        }
    }

    fwrite(bytes, 1, 10485760, handle->bestand);
    free(bytes);
    handle->huidig += 10485760;
    handle->positie += 10485760;
    fseek(handle->bestand, handle->huidig, SEEK_SET);
    fseek(handle->nieuwbstnd, handle->positie, SEEK_SET);
    calc = (float)handle->huidig;
    calc /= (float)handle->size;
    calc *= 100.0f;

    if (calc >= 100.0)
    {
        fclose(handle->bestand);
        fclose(handle->nieuwbstnd);
        free(handle);
    }

    return calc;
}
```

EDIT: Solved

Comment: `fwrite(bytes, 1, 10485760, handle->bestand);` <- wouldn't you want to write to `handle->nieuwbstnd` there?

Comment: How do you know what's wrong if you don't check the return value from `fread_s()`?  Also, you can control error reporting (at least in the TR24731 or C 2011 versions of the `*_s()` functions) by specifying an error reporting function.

Comment: What's the benefit of writing `if ((i-10485760) < 0)` instead of the simpler, clearer `if (i < 10485760)`?  Fortran II used to require something akin to that sort of circumlocution, but Fortran IV (aka Fortran 66) put an end to the need to do that.

Comment: This function is looped, hence the check at the beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is your specific problem but it *is* something wrong with your code.

When you do an `fread` call, you specify how many "objects" you want to read and the object size, then `fread` will read *up to* that many objects. But it will read an *exact number* of those objects.

So, when you try to read a million one-byte objects from a seven-byte file, you'll get seven of them and the return code will reflect this. However, if you try to read one million-byte object, you'll get nothing at all, and the return code will reflect that.

The reason I emphasize the return value is that you may get back less objects than you wanted (such as if you ask for 1000 one-byte objects where there's only 900 left in the file), so blindly writing the *expected* amount to the output file is a no-no. You need to check the return code and act on that.

In addition, as a commenter points out, you appear to be writing back to the *input* file in one of your output statements:

```
fwrite (bytes, 1, 10485760, handle->bestand);
```

That's unlikely to end well :-) It should probably be:

```
fwrite (bytes, 1, 10485760, handle->nieuwbstnd);
```

Comment: But it is big enough (100MB), I checked in the previous code how big the file is. And I said that reading 10485760 1 bytes won't work either (even though it returns 10485760).

Comment: @Ruben, it doesn't matter how big the file is, `fread` may still decide to give you less and you should allow for that.

Comment: Writing to the input file was the problem, the value of bytes doesn't show up in the debugger (to big I guess?).

Comment: @paxdiablo: `fread` may not "decide to give you less". `fread` is specified to behave exactly the same as the corresponding number of calls to `fgetc` (plus locking to make the whole operation atomic, on some implementations including any conforming to POSIX). There is no option for an implementation to give up early. The only way `fread` should return less than the full count is a read error or end-of-file status.

Comment: @R.., right, I'm not _entirely_ sure how that's different to what I said - _when_ `fread` may give you less than you asked for is separate to the fact that it _may_ do so. In other words, if you blindly assume that you've gotten the 1M that you asked for in the last read despite the fact there were only twenty bytes left in the file, it will end in grief :-) Nonetheless, since you're usually right about such things, I'll adjust the answer to try make it clearer.

Answer (score 1):

```
bytes = (char*)malloc(i);
// etc.
fread_s(&bytes, i, 1, i, handle->bestand); // Here and down below
```

You want `bytes` here, not `&bytes` since the address in `bytes` is where your buffer lives.

Comment: I'm actually surprised it doesn't crash on you, but it's undefined behavior, so anything can happen (even nothing). :)

Comment: Thanks, I didn't see that :)

Comment: Nor did I, +1 for that, it's likely to be a problem.